# how to exlude empty spaces from "if-else" statments - JS

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I searched for how to exclude empty spaces like " " or "     " or "            " from an if statments but i didnt find any relevant topic

i have an html page which add a value to an array everytime the user types in a value inside the input field
but i want to exclude the spaces, for example if the user enter only empty spaces, i dont want them to be pushed inside the values[] array

this is my jscode :

```
const values = []
const inputEL = document.getElementById("field-input")
  if (inputEL.value){
    values.push(inputEL.value)
    inputEL.value = ""
  }
```

I tried this but it didn't work as expected, user still can enter empty spaces and they are pushed inside the array:

```
if (!inputEL.value || inputEL.value === " "){
    console.log("field input is  empty / user enter empty spaces")
else{
    values.push(inputEL.value)
    inputEL.value = ""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) to remove whitespaces from the beginnen and end of the string.

So if the input is `" "`, you well `trim()` it down to `""` which is a falsy value in your `if`:

```js
const values = []
const inputEL = document.getElementById("field-input");
const trimmed = inputEl.value.trim();
if (trimmed){
    values.push(trimmed)
    inputEL.value = ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a pattern and a required attribute to combine the requirement

```html
<form>
  <input name="name" required pattern=".*\S+.*" title="can't include only whitespace">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

then you can also use `input.validity.valid` to check if it's valid or not

Answer (score -1):

You can use `string.trim()` method, it return a new array with whitespaces removed from both ends, (start and end) without modifying the original one

Comment: Arrays don't have trim... you are confusing it with strings

Comment: `trim()` is a `String.prototype` function, there is no `array.trim`

Comment: sorry my bad, I was supposed to write String which the OP has asked, edit the answer